# How can I Create ID from URL using Modrewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file I have the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In my index.php I have the following code:

```
<?php
$id_1 = isset( $_GET['id'] ) ? rtrim( trim( $_GET['id'] ), '/' ) : 'default';
?>
```

Currently, if I use a URL in the following format

http://mydomain.com/directory/name/

The modrewrite grabs /name/ as $id_1

I would like to change the format of the url to grab a second $id_2 as follows

http://mydomain.com/directory/1/name/

my question is how do I change the modrewrite and the php code to capture both $id_1 and $id_2

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id_1=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id_1=$1&id_2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

the QSA means query_string_add so if you call for

http://mydomain.com/directory/1/name/?foo=bar
the rewrite engine will translate to
http://mydomain.com/directory/?id_1=1&id_2=name&foo=bar

Comment: Thanks CaSUaL.  I was trying to take the URL in my example http://mydomain.com/directory/1/name/ and make $id_1 = 1 and $id_2 = name.  Apologies if my question wasn't clear.